# Disable GWT RPC requests getting encoded

Tags: gwt, rpc, loadrunner

How can I stop Gwt-Rpc requests getting encoded sent through the browser. The payload of the body currently has this format

```
7|0|24|http://192.168.1.167:7373/reservationCentral/reservationcentral/|0EF6245E352394C4BB722ECF8159F0EC|it.codegen.gwt.client.DataService|execute|java.lang.String/2004016611|it.codegen.gwt.shared.DefaultAction/363730338|it.codegen.tbx.gwt.central.module.reservation.shared.action.UpdateBookingInfoAction/2387171193|it.codegen.tbx.gwt.central.data.reservation.BookingInfoRpc/1217200749||shamitha|it.codegen.tbx.gwt.central.data.CGWebDate/3706720768|NOT SAVED|FIT|STD|RCL|DIRECT|E-mail|C|Silva|it.codegen.tbx.gwt.central.data.CGWebTimestamp/3979480346|NONE|USD|$|{booking_ID}|1|2|3|4|2|5|6|0|7|8|0|-1|P__________|9|0|0|0|-1|0|0|9685|10|11|9|10|2014|NHHmLkiFinh|0|1000|12|13|14|0|15|-1|0|Lfd102XJx1c|9|9|16|9|17|9|0|0|0|0|0|11|9|10|2014|0|18|9|0|A|11|9|10|2014|0|0|0|19|20|9|17|918|48|10|16|2014|0|9|0|0|100|21|0|P__________|0|0|11|9|10|2014|22|23|0|P__________|24|13|1|30000|50000|1|0|0|
```

Comment: What do you mean "stop getting encoded" isnt that encoding part of the protocol?

Comment: yes, can I config the app not to encode the requests like this so they would be appeared as just plain http calls.

Comment: This is part of the GWT protocol, not related to LoadRunner.

Comment: @Shamitha Silva, are you writing a test, which is talking directly to GWT-RPC services?

Comment: Yes in my application I do call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to recording options - Advance (under HTTP Properties) - there is a options for header, content and Non Resource. you can add or remove GWT here.

Comment: By doing this you wont be able to correlate the parameters. Anyway thanks for your reply.